# How to clone my HHD to SSD on my mid-2009 Macbook Pro

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, carbon-copy-cloner

I'm trying to clone my 680GB HDD to a new 500GB SSD, trying EaseUS and Carbon Copy Cloner. The goal is to replace my HDD with the SSD, so I need to boot from it. There's only about 100GB of used disk space on my HDD so I figured it's doable to clone, unless it's literally trying to copy every sector, empty or not, in which case my SSD is too small.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Would using the Disk Utility be another option? I've read up on Time Machine, or Restore option in Disk Utility, but it's hard to find a clear answer and so far what I've tried hasn't worked. I managed to copy the contents over to the SSD but it won't boot up from it. And when I tried reassigning the startup disk to my SSD, it still didn't boot from it. Not sure what else to try. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Carbon Copy Cloner is perfectly capable of making bootable clones, internal, external, SSD or HD, doesn't matter. Check your method.

Comment: @Tetsujin I ran CCC last night, left it running and checked this morning. I came back to a black screen with a mouse cursor I could move, but could do nothing else. I shut it down. When I restarted it, none of my apps open now. Any idea what could have happened? It was a very simple method I used in CCC. Literally just dragged my current HD to the source icon, SSD to the destination icon, and clicked Clone. This is super frustrating now that I can't open anything up.

Comment: That points more to some issue with the drive you were trying to clone from than CCC itself.

Comment: An issue I've never encountered before, only after the CCC clone process was attempted. Must have been something during that process that triggered this. Any idea what that could be? The error report says "termination reason namespace codesigning code 0x1"

Comment: Google says  "Termination Reason: Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 0x1" means that the app certificate was revoked. I have no clue what that *actually* means, but it looks like something went wrong with Gatekeeper. I'd check with CCC's devs,  https://bombich.com/ to see if they know what happened.

Comment: I don't believe in cloning unless you absolutely have to.  Do a clean install instead.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't recommend having the boot drive mounted to do a proper clone. If you have an external drive (preferably firewire 800 for that model, but USB 2 will also work), install a current versions of macOS onto it. Boot to that drive by restarting and holding down the Option key at boot, and you can select the external bootable drive. Now that you are booted to your external, install your clone software of choice, in your case Carbon Copy Cloner (I personally like SuperDuper! but that is me). Once you have the software installed, start cloning the boot disk to the new SSD.

As a side note, make sure that you partition your new SSD before you start the process. That way you don't run into an error because it is FAT32 partitioned and not GUID.

Comment: There is absolutely no issue with using CCC to back up the current boot drive. I've been doing it for years with zero issues ever.

Comment: It cuts down on possible issues. I've done it for years as well, but I have found that taking one more possible fail point out of the mix is good practice.